# React hooks inside of a Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried creating my own React-Setup and it worked until I tried using Hooks.

If you look at the Home route, it crashes immediately with the message => "Invalid Hook call"
If you look at the Login route, it works as expected, but with an Eslint error  (Not sure why it's even there, wouldn't know how to do it differently )
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-mccarthy-p61vm

I've tried using "hookrouter" and the error in the Home component went away. Looking further revealed React Router to be a class based Component, and nesting (rendering ?) a Functional Component doesn't allow me to use Hooks in said Functional Component.

But nesting previous Functional Component inside another Functional "Wrapper"Component results in proper (I think) behavior for Hooks.

I feel like I'm missing something important here.

Comment: Follow up this. Issue raised on official package https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088
There are so many answers there. Try them

Comment: @ZunaibImtiaz Sorry I don't see anything relevant in that thread ?